# condtion in javascript validation not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox and a submit button

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate()"/>
```

Here is the function code:

```
if (document.getElementById("usernameee").value == null || document.getElementById("usernameee").value == "" ) {
  document.getElementById("usernameee").style.borderColor = 'red';
  return false
} else {
  document.getElementById("usernameee").style.borderColor = '';
  if (document.getElementById("usernameee").value.length!=0 ||   document.getElementById("usernameee").value.length < 8 ) {
  document.getElementById("usernameee").style.borderColor = 'red';
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Enter Atleast 8 Characters"
  return false
} else {
  document.getElementById("usernameee").style.borderColor = '';
}
```

now what is want is that if the user leaves the filed empty it should only highlight the textbox with backgound color red and if the username is less than 8 characters it should show the message and highlight the backgound of textbox  but now even if the textbox is empty it is displaying the message which i dont want...if the field is empty it should ol

Comment: Use `else if` for your second check.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second conditional is wrong. Also you can write the code much cleaner like this:

```
var username = document.getElementById("usernameee");

if(!username.value) {
  //There is no username
  username.style.borderColor = 'red';
} else if(username.value.length < 8) {
  //There is a username and the value is shorter than 8 characters
  username.style.borderColor = 'red';
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Enter Atleast 8 Characters";
} else {
  //There is a username and it is longer than or equal to 8 characters.
  username.style.borderColor = '';
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
}
```